# How to make if else checkbox enabled/disabled in sql query and asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to make my checkbox is enabled and disable when user login from my data

My syntaks in asp.net:

```
   if (Session["Berhasil"] != null)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Berhasil..";
            if(Label1 = "select * from cs100020 where countno=2 and status=3");
            {
                cbxinven.Enabled=true
                cbxfinadmin.Enabled=true
                cbxkaskecil.Enabled=true
                cbxemail.Enabled=false
                cbxsap.Enabled=false
                cbxpc.Enabled=false
                cbxuserad.Enabled=false
            }
            else (Label1="select * from cs100020 where countno=3 and status=3);
            {
                cbxinven.Enabled=false
                cbxfinadmin.Enabled=false
                cbxkaskecil.Enabled=false
                cbxemail.Enabled=true
                cbxsap.Enabled=true
                cbxpc.Enabled=true    
                cbxuserad.Enabled=true
            }    
        }
```

and i got error :
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

Source Error:

Line 137:                cbxuserad.Enabled=false
Line 138:            }
Line 139:            else (Label1="select * from cs100020 where countno=3 and status=3);
Line 140:            {
Line 141:                cbxinven.Enabled=false

Source File: d:\Sharing\Budiman\IAPHRM BACKUP 08022019\IapHRM_180119_Backup\ViewCS.aspx.cs    Line: 139

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **closing** double quote on the SQL statement for the ELSE branch (i.e. else (Label1 = .... line) is missing.

Comment: I try to correct:

```
            else(Label1.Text = "select * from cs100020 where countno=2 and status=3");

```

and i got this :

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'else'

Comment: you need to remove ";" from both the IF and the ELSE branch. ";" is for the end of a statement. In this case, it can appear only after the the closing bracket of the ELSE branch but you don't have to use it there